# How to update GTK for Kmoddo Editor in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gtk

I am trying to install latest Komodo Editor and when I run the setup in terminal, following shows up:

"Komodo requires version 2.24 or greater. Please update gtk-2.0. While Komodo will still install correctly, it may not run."

Ubuntu Software is up to date.there're no software updates to be install. How can i fix this?